# Google Form Script Editor: How to show an image uploaded in the Form through a Discord Webhook?

Tags: google-apps-script, discord, webhooks, google-forms

I copied a script from the internet to manage sending a webhook on Discord and I'm trying to understand how to make it accept images. At the end of my Google Form I want to put a response being an Image to Upload, and this show at the end of the webhook message.

This is the Script I'm using

```js
const webhooks = [ "" ];

/* Start of optional section */
const title = "MODULO ARRESTI"; /*    Add a nice custom title, to make the script truly yours.    */
const avatarImage = ""; /*    The logo of your brand or Discord server, maybe?    */
const shortDescription = ""; /*    A little bit of information about the response received, so you don't forget in the future?    */
const colour = "#008080"; /*    A custom colour? Example: #78A8C6    */
const mention = ""; /*Mention yourself or a role - it should look like <@!7890975289098612689> or <@&7890975289098612689>    */
/* End of optional section */


const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
const allResponses = form.getResponses();
const latestResponse = allResponses[ allResponses.length - 1 ];
const response = latestResponse.getItemResponses();
var items = [];

if ( !webhooks ) throw "You forgot the webhook :)";

function embedText( e ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ ) {
        const question = response[ i ].getItem().getTitle();
        const answer = response[ i ].getResponse();
        if ( answer == "" ) continue;
        items.push( { "name": question, "value": answer } );
        function data( item ) { return [ `**${ item.name }**`,`${ item.value }` ].join( "\n" ); }
    }

    try {
      if ( avatarImage !== null ) {
          const embedSetup = { "method": "post", "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, muteHttpExceptions: true, "payload": JSON.stringify( { "content": ( mention ) ? `${ mention }` : " ", "embeds": [ { "title": ( title ) ? title : form.getTitle(), "thumbnail": { "url": encodeURI( avatarImage ) }, "color": ( colour ) ? parseInt(colour.substr(1), 16) : Math.floor( Math.random() * 16777215 ), "description": ( shortDescription ) ? `${ shortDescription }\n\n${ items.map( data ).join( '\n\n' ) }` : items.map( data ).join( '\n\n' ), "timestamp": new Date().toISOString(), } ] } ) };
          for ( var i = 0; i < webhooks.length; i++ ) { UrlFetchApp.fetch( webhooks[ i ], embedSetup ); }
          return form.deleteResponse( latestResponse.getId() );
      } else {
          const embedSetup = { "method": "post", "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, muteHttpExceptions: true, "payload": JSON.stringify( { "content": ( mention ) ? `${ mention }` : " ", "embeds": [ { "title": ( title ) ? title : form.getTitle(), "color": ( colour ) ? parseInt(colour.substr(1), 16) : Math.floor( Math.random() * 16777215 ), "description": ( shortDescription ) ? `${ shortDescription }\n\n${ items.map( data ).join( '\n\n' ) }` : items.map( data ).join( '\n\n' ), "timestamp": new Date().toISOString(), } ] } ) };
          for ( var i = 0; i < webhooks.length; i++ ) { UrlFetchApp.fetch( webhooks[ i ], embedSetup ); }
          return form.deleteResponse( latestResponse.getId() );
      }
    } catch(error) {
      return Logger.log(error);
    }
}
```

And this is what I get from the Webhook (excuse me for the Italian Language, it's not important to read the content anyway, every Bold text is a Form Question and below there's the response)
[image]

---

Also on a side note I'd like two ask 2 more questions related to this webhook:

1. Is it possible to change the Text Format of a data whe it gets printed? The form google always print as YYYY-MM-DD, I was wondering if it's possible to change the format for example in DD-MM-YYYY.
2. At the end of the Discord Message, there's the date of when the message got sent; is it possible to change that small text in something else, perhaps a custom sentence with a dynamic information connected to a response of the Form, like the name of the person that compiled the form?

By uploading an image with the script I sent I just got this on the response:

[image]